# Show about a kid who is transported to a world where people fight monsters. One monster was a big, floating, electric jellyfish

Tags: story-identification, tv, isekai

The show followed a kid who somehow got transported to another world where you fight with monsters. And he got to make friends with two other people; one of them a guy who had a sister who was better at fighting than him. I can't remember the other person, but the main character in his house found a picture of a monster that might have been the thing that transported him, but I'm not sure. And another monster was a big, floating, electric jellyfish, and that's all I can remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this live-action or animated? If animated, was it 2D or 3D (computer-generated) animation? Also, in roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?